# Cannot subscript a value of type [String: AnyObject]? with an index of type String

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I know have many the same question but still cannot find the way to fix my error. Please see the image for more detail. I used Xcode 7 and swift 2.0

[image]

**Edit:** fcking the warning of Swift. finnaly `(change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]?.boolValue)!` fixed the error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`change` is an optional. Either unwrap the optional

```
let isCaptureStillImage = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]!.boolValue
```

or use optional bindings

```
if let changeNewKey = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] {
  let isCaptureStillImage = changeNewKey.boolValue

...
```