# Getting this error when trying to parse a json object

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

[I am using swift and m getting this error when trying to parse a JSON object, i did so many changes to my code but still cannot find the right solution to fix my error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYF4a.png)

```
 if let subs_service_objects = subs_arry["subscription"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{



                                     if let subs_service_object = subs_service_objects["my_regular_service"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]{
                                        let listService =  List<service_details>()


                                        print("value ahhhsa" + "(subs_arrynew)" )

                                        for _subslist in subs_service_object{

                                            let mySubsObj = service_details()


                                            mySubsObj.count = (_subslist["count"] as? Int)!
                                            mySubsObj.service_name = (_subslist["service"] as? String)!

                                            mySubsObj.service_id = (_subslist["service"] as? String)!


                                            self.SaveSubsList.saveSubsList(mySubsObj)
                                            listService.insert(mySubsObj, atIndex: listService.count)

                                        }


                                        print(self.SaveSubsList.getSubsalist())
                                        mySubs.rg_service = listService


                                    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727025/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-string-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type-s
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32711613/cannot-subscript-a-value-of-type-string-anyobject-with-an-index-of-type-stri

Comment: did you mean as? [string : Anyobject] rather than as?[ [string : Anyobject]] ?

Comment: Is this supposed to be subs_arry["subscription"].array? I don't think you're stating the type, that's why the error is appearing.